# Please add a `[editing]` magic link in comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, magic-links

In a comment, I'd love to be able to say:

> please foo the bar information by [editing] your question.

but I can't. The closest I can get is:

> please foo the bar information by [edit]ing your question.

which works, but is pretty ugly. It'd be great to have an `[editing]` magic link in comments.

Comment: What's wrong with a simple rearrangement? "Please [edit] your question and add the foo the bar information"

Comment: @DavidPostill at the time I wrote the comment, a grammatically correct rearrangement eluded me :P
in principal there's nothing wrong with it, but that doesn't change the fact that this would be nice to have.

Comment: Whilst not the ideal solution, my [Make your own custom “magic links” for comments!](http://stackapps.com/q/6650/26088) userscript can let you do that if it bugs you enough to make you install it! :)